# Do the locatives militiae, terrā, marī occur by themselves?

Tags: syntax, morphology, locative

Textbooks tell us that the only common (in the sense of not proper) nouns that have a locative case are *rūs* "countryside" and *domus* "home". However, I'm familiar with two expressions that use coordinated nouns in the locative:

- *domī mīlitiaeque* "at home and on campaign"
- *terrā marīque* "by land and by sea" (ETA: I shouldn't have referred to these as locatives -- the first is clearly ablative and the second probably likewise)

But I only recall seeing the locative forms *mīlitiae, terrā, marī* as part of those fixed expressions, not by themselves. Are they ever used by themselves? Do classical authors use *mīlitiae* for "on campaign" outside of the phrase *domī mīlitiaeque*, etc.?

(Prompted by [this question](https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/2791/best-translation-for-at-sea).)

Comment: Besides *ruri* and *domi*, you also have *humi* "on the ground."

Comment: Why do your feel that terra and mari are in the locative case? Aren't those regular ablatives of location?

Comment: @Cerberus, you're quite right about *terrā* -- not sure why I was thinking of it as a locative (except that the phrase reminded me of *domī mīlitiaeque*!) *Marī* could formally be a locative, but I suppose it's better seen as an ablative too. Editing the question...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- ***terrā:*** Was used stand-alone by Cicero [here:](http://www.thelatinlibrary.com/cicero/plancio.shtml#96) *Brundisium terrā petere* ”to head towards Brindisi by land.”
- ***marī:*** According to F. Calonghi, *Dizionario latino-italiano*, 3th ed., 1969, was used stand-alone by Cornelius Nepos with the meaning “by sea”. Unfortunately, without precise reference. However, see Cicero’s quotation below.
- ***militiae:*** According to L. Castiglioni - S. Mariotti, *Vocabolario della lingua latina*, 4th ed., 2007, was used stand-alone by Cicero with the meaning ”in wartime”. Again, no precise reference, but see edit below.

Neither expression that you mention is fixed: you get very many examples of variations like *militiae domique,* *et mari et terra,* *mari terraque,* *aut mari aut terra.*

Technically, neither *terrā* nor *marī* are locatives. They are regular ablatives: *terra*'s locative, if it existed, should be *terrae;* *mare* does have an ablative *mare* used by Lucretius, Ovidius and other poets but you get zillions of examples of *in mari, a mari, de mari,* and there is no doubt about which form is the preferred one. So *terrā* and *marī* belong in the list of locative ablatives, together with *dextrā, laevā* (on the right, left), *speciē* (under the pretext), *linguā* (in the language) and so on. They are closely related to ablatives of manner, and in fact they seem not to refer to a *location* (at land, at sea) but to a *manner of displacement* (by land, by sea). Locatives like *domī* or *rurī* are never used together with adjectives (*domī meae* et sim. being an exception); on the contrary, Cicero writes for instance [here:](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus:text:1999.02.0010:text=Man.:chapter=11&highlight=mari): *cum aut hieme aut referto praedonum mari navigaret* (sailing either in winter or through a pirate-infested sea) with ablatives without preposition.

Finally, I would like to point out that it is possible that the meaning of *terrā marīque* evolved from the simple coordinated use of both components. I have the example of Italian, where *per mare e per terra* has become just an imaginative way of saying “everywhere” (much like “over land and sea”), while *per terra* alone has become “on the floor” and in the modern language you have to say *via terra* to get the original meaning of “by land”. Therefore I would suggest that a precise analysis be done before translating such variations as *et mari et terra,* which might have the original meaning of “both by sea and by land”, in contrast to *terra marique* which might have a “diluted” meaning. Each occurrence might be different.

***Edit:*** 
[Lewis and Short](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aentry%3Dmilitia) say:

> *Gen.* militiae, *in military service, or on a campaign, in the field;* freq. in phrase: domi militiaeque, **...** —Also without domi, Cic. Leg. 3, 3, 6; Sall. J. 84, 2; Tac. H. 2, 5.—

but Cicero’s and Tacitus’ occurrences are not convincing at all, and I hope that Castiglioni-Mariotti’s ghost reference is not one of them. OTOH, [*Sall. Jug. 84*](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Sal.%20Jug.%2084.2&lang=original) is peculiar, showing a locative contrasting with an ablative of means: *plerosque militiae, paucos fama cognitos,* i.e. “most [of them] known [to him] by actual service, some few only by report”.